# Can primeng p-menu hash name be made unique when control is in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to use an index or a unique name in the p-menu definition for the hash name when this control is defined in a *ngFor? Secifically:

```
<p-menu #menuChooseOp [popup]="true" [model]="logicalOperator" appendTo="body"></p-menu>
```

When more than one is defined, event handling, based on the hash name "#menuChooseOp" is confused. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not have that.

you can:

in HTML, inside each ngFor item, you can reference the template variable without problem. Angular knows you are referring to the enclosing item.

in the ts file, you can access the group of template variable with a ViewChildren decorator, rather than a ViewChild.

`@ViewChildren('menuChooseOp') menus:QueryList<any>;`